# Jmeter SOAP parameterization with dynamically changing tag blocks

Tags: soap, jmeter

I'm newby in Jmeter and faced the following problem.
I want to realize SOAP request like this:

```
<Envelope>
   <Header>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      ...
      <groupId>1</groupId>
      <users>
         <user>
            <surname>Aaa</surname>
         </user>
         <user>
            <surname>Bbb</surname>
         </user>
         <user>
            <surname>Ccc</surname>
         </user>
         ...
      </users>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

And problem is that number of **user** blocks in **users** can change dynamically up to hundreads. The data defining the number of **users** for each iteration is obtained from an external source - either from a file or from a database. All **user** in each request bound to one value of **groupId**.
So the source file probably will look like this:

```
groupId,user
1, Aaa
1, Bbb
1, Ccc
2, Ddd
2, Eee
3, Fff
...
```

So the question is how can I realize that parameterization?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the request body using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and some [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code.

Example code:

```
def source = new File('test.csv').readLines()

def payload = [:]

source.takeRight(source.size() - 1).each { line ->
    payload.put(line.split(',')[0], source.findAll { it.split(',')[0].equals(line.split(',')[0]) }.collect { it.split(',')[1] })
}

new StringWriter().with { sw ->
    new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(sw).with {
        Envelope {
            Header {

            }
            Body {
                payload.each { entry ->
                    "groupId"(entry.getKey())
                    users {
                        entry.getValue().each { value ->
                            user {
                                "surname"(value)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    log.info(sw.toString())
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Processing XML](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)