# How to dynamically create an XML object in the jmeter PreProcessor

Tags: groovy, jmeter, xml-parsing, jsr223, xmlslurper

Using Jmeter, I want to compose a dynamically-sized, XML object with dynamically-generated content having the structure as the one below in a JSR223 preprocessor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aaa id1="TD00100" id2="005" date="2021-09-06T09:49:57.623Z" id3="Minoan007">
    <p>
        <pa outOfScope="false" inTransit="false" reqID="ID00001">
            <location arrivalDate="2021-09-20" code="ASD" departureDatetime="2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z" scheduleNo="AB123">
            </location>
            <docs dob="1960-09-02" expiryDate="2031-09-13" gen="f" givenName="Test1" anotherCode="AB" anotherCode2="ABC" surname="John" docNr="100000001" docType="J">
            </docs>
        </pa>
        <pa eesetiasOutOfScope="false" inTransit="false" pReqID="ID00002">
            <location arrivalDate="2021-09-20" code="ASD" departureDatetime="2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z" scheduleNo="AB123">
            </location>
            <docs dob="1960-09-02" expiryDate="2031-09-13" gen="m" givenName="Test2" anotherCode="AB" anotherCode2="ABC" surname="John" docNr="100000002" docType="J">
            </docs>
        </pa>
        <pa eesetiasOutOfScope="false" inTransit="false" pReqID="ID00003">
            <location arrivalDate="2021-09-20" code="ASD" departureDatetime="2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z" scheduleNo="AB123">
            </location>
            <docs dob="1960-09-02" expiryDate="2031-09-13" gen="f" givenName="Test3" anotherCode="AB" anotherCode2="ABC" surname="John" docNr="100000003" docType="J">
            </docs>
        </pa>       
    </p>
</aaa>
```

I want to have a HTTP Sampler with a static body such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aaa id1="TD00100" id2="005" date="2021-09-06T09:49:57.623Z" id3="Minoan007">
    <p>
        ${xmlObject}
    </p>
</aaa>
```

And in the `${xmlObject}` I want to put a **custom-size XML object based on some variable** and **populate each `<pa> </pa>` object with some small part of the content differently (for example just increasing the id by 1 in each sub-xml object)**, based on some custom defined counter. Something like this example. Say I define a variable to be equal to 100: when the script runs it would generate an object with 100 sub-objects with this structure:

```
<pa .... reqID="ID00001">...</pa> objects
</pa>
<pa .... reqID="ID00002">...</pa> objects
</pa>
<pa .... reqID="ID00003">...</pa> objects
</pa>    

....n

<pa .... reqID="n">...</pa> objects
</pa>
```

And then I just need to move it to a Jmeter variable with using `vars.put` and use it in my HTTP request.

I did something identical from the logic point of view for a JSON object using the JsonSlurper in the JSR223 Preprocessor. I just don't know what to use and how to use it to generate my custom XML object.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a day, but I finally found the solution I needed. Leaving the code here in case it helps someone.
Thanks again to Dmitri T for pointing me in the right direction with those resources.

```
def numberOfNodes = 3 // set how many sub-nodes are needed

def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)


xml.rootNode() {
createRootNode(xml, numberOfNodes, 'ID0000')
}

def createRootNode(builder, repeat, reqID) {
   for (int i = 0 ; i < repeat ; i++) {
       builder.pa(outOfScope:'false', inTransit:'false', reqID:reqID+(i+1).toString() ){
        builder.location (arrivalDate:'2021-09-20', code:'ASD', departureDatetime:'2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z', scheduleNo:'LH8912')
        builder.docs( dob:'1960-09-02' , expiryDate:'2031-09-13', gen:'female', givenName:'Test3', anotherCode:'ABC', anotherCode2:'AB', surname:'John', docNr: 100000001, travelDocType:'J' )
       }
    }
}

def nodeAsText = writer.toString()
log.info(nodeAsText) // print to jmeter log console

vars.put('nodes3XmlObj', nodeAsText) //put the variable as a string into a variable accesible for jmeter
```

Outcome in Jmeter log console:

```
2021-10-13 23:05:28,222 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: <rootNode>
  <pa outOfScope='false' inTransit='false' reqID='ID00001'>
    <location arrivalDate='2021-09-20' code='ASD' departureDatetime='2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z' scheduleNo='LH8912' />
    <docs dob='1960-09-02' expiryDate='2031-09-13' gen='female' givenName='Test3' anotherCode='ABC' anotherCode2='AB' surname='John' docNr='100000001' travelDocType='J' />
  </pa>
  <pa outOfScope='false' inTransit='false' reqID='ID00002'>
    <location arrivalDate='2021-09-20' code='ASD' departureDatetime='2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z' scheduleNo='LH8912' />
    <docs dob='1960-09-02' expiryDate='2031-09-13' gen='female' givenName='Test3' anotherCode='ABC' anotherCode2='AB' surname='John' docNr='100000001' travelDocType='J' />
  </pa>
  <pa outOfScope='false' inTransit='false' reqID='ID00003'>
    <location arrivalDate='2021-09-20' code='ASD' departureDatetime='2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z' scheduleNo='LH8912' />
    <docs dob='1960-09-02' expiryDate='2031-09-13' gen='female' givenName='Test3' anotherCode='ABC' anotherCode2='AB' surname='John' docNr='100000001' travelDocType='J' />
  </pa>
</rootNode>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your "some of the content differently" and "based on some custom defined counter" stanzas don't tell much to be I can only suggest taking a look at [MarkupBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html) class which provides all the necessary functions in order to dynamically construct the XML payloads.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Creating XML](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_creating_xml)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
- [Jmeter SOAP parameterization with dynamically changing tag blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66549839/jmeter-soap-parameterization-with-dynamically-changing-tag-blocks/66551836#66551836)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me how I can print this outcome to the the jmeter log and how I can get the content out from the JSR223 Preprocessor to use in the jmeter request?

Example:

 new MarkupBuilder().root {
   a( a1:'one' ) {
     b { mkp.yield( '3 < 5' ) }
     c( a2:'two', 'blah' )
   }
 }
 
Will print the following to System.out:

 <root>
   <a a1='one'>
     <b>3 &lt; 5</b>
     <c a2='two'>blah</c>
   </a>
 </root>

Comment: To print something to jmeter.log file use `log` shorthand like `log.info('Hello')`. To store something into a JMeter Variable use `vars` shorthand like `vars.put('Hello', 'JustNatural')`. Then use `${Hello}` in your request. More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy). Remember that JMeterVariables are Strings by default so you need to cast the object to string before storing. The same applies to `log` shorthand, it can print only Strings.

Comment: Yes, that is my problem, the fact that I don't know how to cast or convert the outcome of this example which they are giving at the top of your first link MarkupBuilder to a String. They say that it will print the following to System.out which seems to be what I need, but if I try assigning that example code to a variable and then do log.info(variable) it does not work.