# Converting CSV to hashmap - groovy scripting jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, blazemeter

I already created a dynamic xml request payload and I'm pulling some data from CSV file. Now im having a hardtime to convert csv rows and column to hashmap since im a bit new to Groovy scripting.

My csv looks like this

```
itemId, name, lastname
12345, n1, ln1
54321, n2, ln2
66666, n3, ln3
....
```

What I want to achieve is like this

```
{
    "12345": [
        " n1",
        " ln1"
    ],
    "54321": [
        "n2",
        "ln2"
    ] .............
}
```

My code is here

```
def source = new File('1000items.csv').readLines()
def payload = [:]

source.takeRight(source.size() - 1).each { line ->
    payload.put(line.split(',')[0], ----STUCKED HERE----)
}
```

PS. I'm following this guide but im stucked on building the hashmap part

[Jmeter SOAP parameterization with dynamically changing tag blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66549839/jmeter-soap-parameterization-with-dynamically-changing-tag-blocks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a [List](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html) as the 2nd argument and fill it with the remaining values from the current line.

Something like:

```
source.takeRight(source.size() - 1).each { line ->
    def entry = line.split(',')
    payload.put(entry[0], [entry[1], entry[2]])
}
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: A slight variation:
`def payload = source.tail().collect{ it.split(',')*.trim() }.collectEntries{ id, name, lastname -> [id, [name, lastname]] }`

Answer (score 0):

```js
def data = '''itemId, name, lastname
12345, n1, ln1
54321, n2, ln2
66666, n3, ln3
'''

//instead if `data` you can use `new File(...)`
def payload = data.readLines()
       .tail()
       .findAll{it}                 //filter out empty lines 
       .collect{it.split(',\\s*')}  //split by coma and optional spaces
       .collectEntries{ [it[0], [it[1], it[2]]] }

println new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString()
```

all groovy List methods you can find here:

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html